# How to insert results of a stored procedure (sp_whoisactive) into a table in SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server

We have issues in our Azure SQL Managed Instance database and am trying to collect some stats to help us troubleshoot the issues. So I have created a table called [dbo].[WhoIsActive] with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WhoIsActive](
    [dd hh:mm:ss.mss] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [session_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sql_text] [xml] NULL,
    [login_name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [wait_info] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [CPU] [varchar](30) NULL,
    --[tran_log_writes] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [tempdb_allocations] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [tempdb_current] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [blocking_session_id] [smallint] NULL,
    [reads] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [writes] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [physical_reads] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [used_memory] [varchar](30) NULL,
    --[query_plan] [xml] NULL,
    [status] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    --[tran_start_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [open_tran_count] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [percent_complete] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [host_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [database_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [program_name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [start_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [login_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [request_id] [int] NULL,
    [collection_time] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [cx_collection_time]    Script Date: 2/28/2023 7:17:59 AM ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [cx_collection_time] ON [dbo].[WhoIsActive]
(
    [collection_time] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then I have created a widely known stored proc sp_whoisactive latest version from https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases

The next step is to insert the results of the proc into a table periodically.

Option 1:
I have tried to do this:

```
Insert Into [dbo].[WhoIsActive]
 Exec sp_whoisactive
```

but getting this error:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_whoisactive, Line 3737 [Batch Start Line 44]
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.*

Option 2:I have tried the following:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @retention INT = 60,
        @destination_table VARCHAR(500) = 'WhoIsActive',
        @destination_database sysname = 'DBATools',
        @schema VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(4000),
        @parameters NVARCHAR(500),
        @exists BIT;

SET @destination_table = @destination_database + '.dbo.' + @destination_table;

--create the logging table
IF OBJECT_ID(@destination_table) IS NULL
    BEGIN;
        EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @get_transaction_info = 1,
                                @get_outer_command = 1,
                                @get_plans = 1,
                                @return_schema = 1,
                                @schema = @schema OUTPUT;
        SET @schema = REPLACE(@schema, '<table_name>', @destination_table);
        EXEC ( @schema );
    END;

--create index on collection_time
SET @SQL
    = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@destination_database)
      + '; IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@destination_table) AND name = N''cx_collection_time'') SET @exists = 0';
SET @parameters = N'@destination_table varchar(500), @exists bit OUTPUT';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @parameters, @destination_table = @destination_table, @exists = @exists OUTPUT;

IF @exists = 0
    BEGIN;
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cx_collection_time ON ' + @destination_table + '(collection_time ASC)';
        EXEC ( @SQL );
    END;

--collect activity into logging table
EXEC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @get_transaction_info = 1,
                        @get_outer_command = 1,
                        @get_plans = 1,
                        --@destination_table = [WhoIsActive];
                        @destination_table = @destination_table;



--purge older data
SET @SQL
    = 'DELETE FROM ' + @destination_table + ' WHERE collection_time < DATEADD(day, -' + CAST(@retention AS VARCHAR(10))
      + ', GETDATE());';
EXEC ( @SQL );
```

I am now getting this error message:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

So my question is, what is the best way to store this data into a table? Or is there anything am doing wrong?

Comment: The error is telling you the target table schema has extra/missing/mispelled column(s).

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to spot in the literal strings; for example a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Comment: It's also generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to (which here, you do, on your **injected** parameter `@retention`).

Comment: I don't know why anybody would use that 5,500 line monster, but if you insist it does have a `@destination_table` parameter that's incorrectly specified as `varchar(4000)`.